# Windows CMD %ERRORLEVEL% in nested IF

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a Windows 7 logon script first I want to test, if a certain file exists. If (and only if) that is the case, I want to test, if a certain registry key exists. If that is not the case, I want to do some stuff. So here's what I came up with:

```
IF EXIST %SOME_FILE% (
    REG QUERY "HKCU\..." /v some_key
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%=="1" (
        do_some_stuff
    )
)
```

The problem I'm encountering is the fact, that %ERRORLEVEL% is equal to 0, if the file exists - not if the registry key exists. If I don't do the file test, everything is fine. Now, I could use labels and goto, but I'm not really a friend of that. Is there a (simple) alternative?

Comment: `if errorlevel 1 ( ....` and, please, do a search about `delayed expansion` in batch files

Comment: Read the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) and run in a command prompt window `if /?` and read the output help pages. In your case `if errorlevel 1` meaning if exit code of previous application is greater or equal 1 is sufficient.

Comment: ...or: `reg query "HKCU\..." /v some_key || do_some_stuff`

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to bash where things seem to be a bit more straightforward - IMHO. Also, when it comes to cmd, Google, SO and other sites have been more helpful than the manpages which is why I tend to look there, first. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested IFs in Windows shell script are nasty.  I'd go with:

```
IF EXIST %SOME_FILE% (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\wuauserv /v type 2>nul || (
        echo Do something
        echo Do something else
        )
    )
```

Have you considered switching to PowerShell?  Note the explicit pathing for REG.EXE.  This removes the risk of someone shoving a pay-loaded REG.EXE in your path.

Comment: I don't do a lot of Windows scripting, which is part of the reason why I avoided PS so far. Besides, I occasionally encounter PCs that don't have PS installed. Also, I'd have to convince my colleague to use PS, too, because I don't want to be the only one to know how to use it... :)

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution? Sure. `%variable%` in a code block is calculated before the code block. What you need is delayed expansion, aka command by command settings of variable contents.

---

Simply add this to the top of your file,

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

and use exclamation points around variables; `!errorlevel!` instead of percent signs.

Although, I agree with Simon Catlin's answer completely.